# Suppose Kn decomposes into edge-disjoint triangles. Prove that 6 | n − 1 or 6 | n − 3.

Tags: graph-theory

My problem is finding a way to prove this. I was thinking that any Kn graph could have at least one triangle as long as n is 3 or higher. Other than that I do not know where to go with proving this is true.

Comment: Hint: Count the edges in two different ways.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notation $K_n$.  Would you mind explaining?

Comment: The notation $K_n$ means that a graph of n vertices is created with a clique on n vertices. For example, if we have $K_4$ then a graph is created with 4 vertices with each vertice having an edge connecting to every other vertice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: To show this, you want to show that $n$ is odd and that $n$ is not equivalent to $2\bmod 3$. It's good to do those separately.

For each part, it's useful to look at some examples. Why can't you split the edges of $K_4$ into three edge-disjoint triangles? How about $K_5$? Try counting things, like degrees or the total number of edges.

Answer (score 1):

Every vertex $v$ must have even degree, as each triangle will account for two edges with vertex $v$, and every edge belongs to a triangle.  Thus $n$ is odd.

Combining with $3|\frac{n(n-1)}2$ we get the result.